# AngularJS : How to change scope value from isolated scope within directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

How can I change the scope value from a directive? I've tried in this way:

in the template:

```
<h1>{{abcd}}</h1>
<example-directive abcd="abcd"></example-directive>
```

in the directive

```
..
scope: {
   abcd: '='
},
link: function($scope){
   $scope.abcd = "change it pleeease";
}
....
```

but as a result I got back nothing. So the 'h1' tag is empty....
Do anybody know why?

## update1 - my complete code

Directive:

```
(function(){
'use strict';

var standingsDirective = function(api, $http){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope : {
            sid: '=',
            loadingstatus: '='
        },
        templateUrl: "teams/views/standings.html",
        link: function(scope){
            scope.loadingstatus = "loading";

            $http.get(api+'/getsomething'+scope.id).success(function(result){
                scope.data =  result;

                if(scope.data && scope.data.length > 0){
                    scope.loadingstatus = "loaded";
                }else{
                    scope.loadingstatus = "notloaded";
                }
            }).error(function(){
                scope.loadingstatus = "notloaded";
            });
        }
    };
};

var teamsModule = angular.module('app.teams');
teamsModule.directive('standings', ['api', '$http', standingsDirective]);
```

}());

a template file:

```
...
<a ng-show="loadingstatus == 'loaded'" ng-click="subview='standing'" class="activeLink">standings - {{loadingstatus}}</a>
...
<standings sid="sid" loadingstatus="loadingstatus" ng-show="subview=='standing'"></standings>
...
```

Comment: you are injecting some dependencies but the directive function is not prepared to receive them, it should be like: `var standingsDirective = function(api, $http){...` please check that out.

Comment: yes, you were right. But still it's not working. :(

Comment: That's a silly question... is the directive placed under a controller on your HTML code?

Comment: nope, my controller below the directive implementation

Comment: I mean, is the directive *inside* the scope of the controller?

Comment: yep it should be. I placed it within the controller's template. (defined by ui-router)

Comment: any errors on the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my question:

First of all, thanks so much "Fedaykin" to help me out with his comments. He was the one who pointed that it should work so the problem should be in another part in my code.

Figured-out that an ng-if attribute blocked the execution of my directive.
Here is how html code looked like:

```
<a ng-show="loadingstatus == 'loaded'" ng-click="subview='standing'" class="activeLink">standings - {{loadingstatus}}</a>
<div ng-if="subview=='standing'">
    ...
    <standings sid="sid" loadingstatus="loadingstatus" ng-show=" subview=='standing'">    </standings>
    ....
</div>
```

So that caused this strange behaviour.
I hope this post will help the other guys figuring out the problem if they have a similar one.

Comment: Glad to help, that´s why it is important to share as much code as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it should work, I don't know what can be wrong, maybe if you share more of your code we can pinpoint the problem.

Here is a working example, very simple:
http://plnkr.co/edit/eXhog9wsslyuHEZO2dOY

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

});

app.directive('exampleDirective',[function(){
  return{
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      name: '='
    },
    link: function($scope){
      $scope.name = "change it pleeease";
    }
  }
}]);
```

And here is a more detailed example about sharing data between controllers and directives:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Q1VdKJP2tpvqqJL1LF6m?p=preview

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'll share more of my code soon.

Comment: looking forward for your answer